# About the kernel of a finite Frobenius group

Tags: group-theory, permutations

A Frobenius group $G$ is a transitive permutation group which is not regular, but in which only the identity has more than one fixed point. Let $K=\{x\in G \vert x=1 \  or \ x \ has \ no \ fixed \  point \}$. Then $K$ is called the Frobenius kernel of $G$.

It is known that if $G$ is finite, then $K$ is a regular normal subgroup of $G$. My question: Is $K$ an elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$, in general?

If it is possible, I want to prove this statement directly, using some basic facts and definitions. I examine some directions but all of them need another assumptions more than being $G$ finite.

I will be so grateful because of your help.

Comment: $K$ need not to be elemantary abelian $p$ group ?

Comment: This is not true in general. You wrote "$K$ is elementary abelian since $K$ is nilpotent". Where do you get that from? Not all nilpotent groups are elementary abelian. Perhaps you have missed out some extra hypotheses?

Comment: I got the problem. So, I edited my question. If $K$ is not elementary abelian $p$-group in general, maybe the following assumptions can be useful: "Suppose that $G$ is a Frobenius primitive permutation group with abelian point stabilizers."

Comment: If $G$ is primitive, then $K$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. The fact that $K$ is nilpotent then implies that it is elementary abelian. I don't see any way of deducing this without using the difficult theorem (due to John Thompson) that $K$ is nilpotent. I don't think the stabilizers being abelian helps.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thank you so much because of your helpful comments. Would you please explain why a minimal normal subgroup that is nilpotent is elementary abelian?

Comment: There is a general result that says that a minimal normal subgroup of any finite group is a direct product of isomorphic simple groups. So if the group is nilpotent (or even solvable) then the simple group must be cyclicof prime order, so the subgroup is elementary abelian. See for exampe http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587612

Comment: I got the point. Thank you so much.