# Complement for a minimal normal subgroup in a solvable group

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a solvable group, $N$ a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ and suppose that exist $H$ a proper subgroup of $G$ such that $G=NH$. I want to prove that there is a complement of $N$ in $G$.

Right now I don't know how to start with this. Any hints?

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587612/every-minimal-normal-subgroup-of-a-finite-solvable-group-is-elementary-abelian?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

What does '$G$ is solvable' tell you about the structure of a minimal normal subgroup $N$ of $G$?

Use this to show $N\cap H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: $N$ is $p$ elementary abelian, a $p$ group and then a  nilpotent group. Yep, that works. Thanks so much for your answer.