# A minimal normal group of a solvable group is abelian

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

Definition: We say that $H$ is a minimal normal group of $G$ if $H\lhd{G}$ and $\forall K\lneq{H}$ , $K\neq{\{e}\}$ it holds that $ K\ntriangleleft{G}$.

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group, and let $H$ be a minimal normal group of $G$.
Prove that $H$ is abelian.

I wrote a solution but it feels too easy and it proves a stronger claim- that $Z(G)=H$ , so I think it might be wrong:

Since every $g\in{Z(G)}$ commutes with every $h\in{H}$ , it holds that $Z(G)\leq{Z(H)}\leq{H}$. Since $Z(G)\lhd{G}$ , and $H$ is a minimal normal group of $G$, we get that $Z(G)=H$ or $Z(G)={\{e}\}$ . But $G$ is solvable, so we get $Z(G)\neq{\{e}\}$ and therefore $Z(G)=H$ and $H$ is abelian.

I'd like to know if this proof is correct, and if it's wrong, some guidence would be much appreciated.

Comment: carefully recheck your argument that $Z(G)\leqslant Z(H)$; let $g\in Z(G)$. are you sure that $g\in H$ necessarily? for instance, consider the group $G=\mathbb{Z}\big/4\mathbb{Z}$. then $Z(G)=G$, but what is $G$'s minimal normal subgroup? (note that your definition of minimal normal subgroup is *slightly* off, as you need to specify that $H$ is non-trivial. otherwise every group has only $\{e\}$ as minimal normal subgroup!)

Comment: $S_3$ is solvable; but $Z(S_3)=\{e\}$. Your claim that solvable groups have nontrivial center is false.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587612/every-minimal-normal-subgroup-of-a-finite-solvable-group-is-elementary-abelian

Answer (score 1):

Your argument commits several errors.

For one thing, solvable groups may have trivial centers (for example, $S_3$).

For another, It is false that $Z(G)\leq Z(H)$ for $H\leq G$. What is true is that $Z(G)\cap H\leq Z(H)$, but again, in general, there is absolutely no reason to assume that a central element of $G$ must be *in* $H$, and so there is no reason to think it will lie in the center of $H$. When you argue that elements of $Z(G)$ commute with every element of $H$, the conclusion is not that $Z(G)\leq Z(H)$, but rather that $Z(G)\leq C_G(H)$, the centralizer of $H$. The centralizer also contains $Z(H)$, but that doesn’t tell you anything about whether $Z(G)$ and $Z(H)$ have any containment relationship with each other.

As for an argument, here are few things you may want to prove:

1. Subgroups of solvable groups are solvable.
2. If $K$ is solvable, then $[K,K]\neq K$.
3. If $N\triangleleft G$, then $[N,N]\triangleleft G$.

Use those facts to show the desired result.

Comment: could you please elaborate over the third section, which $N \triangleleft G \to [N,N] \triangleleft G$?

Comment: @Jneven: If I wanted to give the proof, I would have included it in th epost instead of suggesting the OP to prove it.

Comment: yes, as this question is from 2 months back, I thought that it could be okay if I'd ask about the general idea of the proof, but it seems that this isn't the purpose of this site. thank you!